# Equation to arrange blocks in a 3D helix

Tags: geometry

I've spent several days trying to figure this out on my own researching similar questions here as well as scouring the internet. I have yet to discover anything that puts into terms a math novice can understand what I am looking for.

In the 3D modeling program Blender, I'm trying to precisely arrange a series of 3D objects in a spiral as in the images attached below (I can't embed the images yet since I'm brand new to this forum). In the attached images, I'm trying to arrange the blue discs into the white helix.

Oblique View:

[image]

Side View:

[image]

Top View:

[image]

The helix in these images has a radius from the middle of the helix to the center of the "tube" of 7 meters. The rise of the helix per turn is 4.2 meters. The radius of the "tube" is 2.1 meters.

I want to arrange the helix so that 26 of the blue discs fit into one revolution of the helix. I need to know the x,y, and z location coordinates as well as the x,y, and z rotation angles for each disc. Ideally, I'd like to have an equation that I could plug into Excel that could produce the coordinates and rotation angles.

Answer (score 1):

The center of each disk rotates around the center of the "donut" (torus), this is, the helix as seen from above. So you must apply a rotation of angle $2\pi/n$ where $n$ is the number of disks.

For the $z$ coordinate apply to each rotated disk a translation $t=h/n$ where $h$ is the height of the helix, how much it goes up in a $2\pi$ spin.

Comment: Thanks for that! Are there separate equations for rotation in the x and y axes?

Comment: Rotation is always around an axis (i.e. a straight line, not necessarily parallel to x, y or z axis). So, rotation in x is an equation and rotate in y is another equation. You may say they can be combined into an unique rotation, true, but the order matters: x and then y is not the same as y and hen x. The needed axis in your case is the z-axis